# Using a changing variable inside an eventListener

Tags: jquery, html5-video, addeventlistener

The var 'endTime' changes but is not being updated within the eventListener.

```
vidposition0 = +$("[data-slide='0']").attr('data-time');
vidposition1 = +$("[data-slide='1']").attr('data-time');

navItem.off().on('click',function(){
  var navid = $(this).attr('data-slide');
  if (navid == 0) {playVideo(vidposition0);}
  if (navid == 1) {playVideo(vidposition1);}
});


function playVideo (endTime) {
  video.play();
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(video.currentTime >= endTime) {
      this.pause();
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`endTime` isn't a variable, it's a function parameter. They behave a lot like **local** function variables. Every call to `playVideo` gets its **own** copy of `endTime`, which gets its value from where `playVideo` is called, and which is private to that call to `playVideo`. Since nothing in `playVideo` is updating it, it never changes.

If it's meant to be changed by something outside the context of a specific call to `playVideo`, you need to move it out of `playVideo` (for instance, make it a variable). But you haven't shown any code where you're updating the value, or given any explanation of what you're doing, so it's hard to be more specific about what to fix.

Comment: Looks to me like a lack of closure. Perhaps a copy of the endtime will make it work so he can do `playVideo (10) {` to play the first 10 secs of the vid